# Changes do not get reflected when getting property by name

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I have the following polymer element

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:mirrors';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

class Column extends Observable{
  @observable String name;
  @observable String displayName;
  Column(this.name,this.displayName);
}

class Model extends Observable{
  @observable String fname;
  @observable String lname;
  @observable int age;

  Model(this.fname,this.lname,this.age);

  operator [](String fieldName){
    var im = reflect(this);
    return im.getField(new Symbol(fieldName)).reflectee;
  }
}


@CustomTag('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {
  @observable ObservableList<Object> data;
  @observable ObservableList<Column> columns;

  MainApp.created() : super.created(){
    columns = new ObservableList.from([new Column("fname","First Name"), new Column("lname","Last name"),new Column("age","Age")]);
    emulateDataChanging();
  }

  emulateDataChanging(){
    var r = new Random();
    var names = ["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee"];
    //add some models to data first
    data = new ObservableList();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      data.add(new Model(names[r.nextInt(4)],names[r.nextInt(4)],r.nextInt(99)));
    }

    //modify couple random props every second
    new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds:1),(t){

      Model m;
      m=(data[r.nextInt(data.length-1)] as Model);
      m.lname=names[r.nextInt(4)];
      m.deliverChanges();
      m=(data[r.nextInt(data.length-1)] as Model);
      m.fname=names[r.nextInt(4)];
      m.deliverChanges();
      m=(data[r.nextInt(data.length-1)] as Model);
      m.age =r.nextInt(4);
      m.deliverChanges();
      //add a random model
      //data.add(new Model(names[r.nextInt(4)],names[r.nextInt(4)],r.nextInt(99)));
    });
  }
}
```

and the html for the element

```
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="main-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>


    <!--A table -->
    <table id="table" class="table table-hover table-mc-light-blue">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th template repeat='{{column in columns}}'>
          {{column.displayName}}
        </th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr template repeat='{{row in data}}'>
        <td template repeat='{{ column in columns}}' data-title="{{column.displayName}}">
          {{row[column.name]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <!--A repeat by binding to the Model properties directly -->
      <template repeat="{{row in data}}">
        <p>{{row.fname}} {{row.lname}} {{row.age}}</p>
      </template>

  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="main_app.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

i added the whole code so one can copy and past and run in seconds, as you can see in the template i have a table and rows are added using a nested repeat and the property of model gets accessed by the name of the column ,and a single repeat where properties get accessed directly.

however the problem when changing a model property, the changes do not get reflected to the table but they get reflected in the other repeat, i think if you run it you'll understand better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You could try two things here in my opinion:*

1. *Use `Observable.dirtyCheck()`*
2. *Call `deliverChanges()` on the polymer element and not on the Model*

**// EDIT**

I think your problem is that you create a new ObservableList() every time. Try to create the ObservableList only once e.g. in your created() contstructor and then change the elements of the list instead of the object.

**// EDIT 2 - Possible Solution**

Hi Again. Now that I understand your problem correctly I have a solution for you. I had the same problem as well. I solved it by writing a wrapper around the model:

**HTML**

```
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="model-wrapper" attributes="model property">
  <template>
    {{value}}
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="model_wrapper.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

**DART**

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:mirrors';

@CustomTag('model-wrapper')
class ModelWrapper extends PolymerElement {
  @published var model;

  @published String property;

  @ComputedProperty('model[property]')
  get value => model[property] == null ? "" : model[property].toString();

  @observable
  set value(v) => model[property] = v; 

  ModelWrapper.created() : super.created(){

  }

  void ready() {
    model.changes.listen((List<ChangeRecord> changes) {
      changes.forEach((record) {
        if(record is PropertyChangeRecord) {
          if(MirrorSystem.getName(record.name) == property) {
            notifyPropertyChange(#value, record.oldValue, record.newValue);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

My original wrapper can be found here:

https://github.com/roberthartung/webui/blob/master/lib/util/webui-property-wrapper.dart
https://github.com/roberthartung/webui/blob/master/lib/util/webui-property-wrapper.html

Comment: i create observable list only once, its not the problem, note the repeat in the bottom shows the changes as it should but not the one in the table rows, tried calling what you suggested, same result

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how you access the data in the Model

```dart
{{row[column.name]}}
```

the `[]` operator access is not observable and `column.name` doesn't change so the expression is never re-evaluated. 
Just because the fields are `@observable` doesn't make the reference using the `[]` operator access `@observable` too.

My attempt - introduce a `dummy` field:

```dart
class Model extends Observable {
  @observable String fname;
  @observable String lname;
  @observable int age;

  @observable String get dummy => '$fname$lname$age';

  getValue(String colName, String dummy) {
    return this[colName];
  }

  Model(this.fname, this.lname, this.age) {
    changes.listen((List<ChangeRecord> c) {
      c.forEach((PropertyChangeRecord r) {
        if(r.name != #dummy) {
          notifyPropertyChange(#dummy, null, dummy);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  operator [](String fieldName){
    var im = reflect(this);
    return im.getField(new Symbol(fieldName)).reflectee;
  }
}
```

and bind the field value like

```dart
{{row.getValue(column.name, row.dummy)}}
```

This way the Polymer binding expression contains a field that changes `row.dummy` and this makes Polymer to re-evaluate the expression.

Comment: i actually tried getters and setters but can you please clarify what do you mean by new Symbol('[]'),something like new Symbol('[fieldName]') in the setter but not Symbol('fieldName')? i could also overload []= and notify in it

Comment: Getters and setters by itself don't change anything. My suggestion is to call `NotifyPropertyChange()` when the values change and for this you need a setter instead of a field to be able to add custom code. I have never tried to call `NotifyPropertyChange()` on an operator (`[]`) but it might work. `[]` would be the function name. Calling `NotifyPropertyChange()` in `[]=` only makes sense when you use the array accessor for setting the values `model['fname'] = 'xxx'` instead of `model.fname = 'xxx'`. I'm not sure if `NotifyPropertyChange()` works for methods too. Seems like I got a bit rusty.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work this way. @Robert s solution should work though.